# Convert Markdown To HTML Symbols

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a program in Haskell that converts markdown to HTML and right now Im trying to write the basic function to convert the main symbols and seem to be having issues with my function and the error code is vague stating  "testing.hs:15:28: parse error on input ‘&’" The following is what I have:

```
symbol x " "        = ""
symbol x (y:ys)
    | x == '&'  = '&amp;' : (symbol ys)
    | x == '<'  = '&lt;'  : (symbol ys)
    | x == '>'  = '&rt;'  : (symbol ys)
    | otherwise = y : (symbol ys)
```

any help in explaining what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated 
thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things which you should rectify: Use `String` instead of `Char` for representing `&amp;`.  Your recursive call to `symbol` is not complete. You are missing some    arguments.

```
symbol :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
symbol x " "        = ""
symbol x (y:ys)
    | x == "&"  = "&amp;" ++  (symbol x ys)
    | x == "<"  = "&lt;" ++ (symbol x ys)
    | x == ">"  = "&rt;"  ++ (symbol x ys)
    | otherwise = y : (symbol x ys)
```

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes are for strings, like "abcd"

Single quotes are for chars, like 'a'

This means absolutely nothing in Haskell- 'abcd', and the compiler will complain.

Also, once you fix that, I want to point out that this

```
"&lt;"  : (symbol ys)
```

will create lists of strings, which you probably don't mean to do....  (++) concatinates strings into strings.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I always get lost with Haskell its hard to think in functional terms when my primary languages are java & C++, I actually had the ++ in their earlier not sure why i removed it